# mySQL Messaging Between Two Users

Tags: mysql

I have a private messaging system that uses a mysql database.

Messages are passed between two users.

However, when any user deletes the conversation history, it should **not be deleted** in the other user.

I could create an Additional column called "deleted_users" and use LIKE when listing messages.

But I'm worried about performance and I need your help.

| id | user_from | user_to | msg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 82 | 85 | test |
| 2 | 85 | 82 | test |

Comment: It sounds like you might need 2 additional columns - `deleted_to` and `deleted_from` to indicate if the _to_ or _from_ user deleted the message.

Comment: Add a 'read' boolean column, change to true if read, I use it and it does not  slow performance down at all and its always saved that way, I would also add a timestamp for future reference.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones They have suggested these columns in other questions, but it is illogical. How do I list the messages that way? The sender and receiver are always different.

Comment: @JulesUK The question is about being deleted, not about being read.

Comment: Oh, I did not realize that these 2 rows represent a single message being sent to/from. This is unnecessary duplication of data, and the message text should be referenced from a separate table. Then you could use a single `deleted` column on this table to indicate which row/user would not see the message anymore.

Comment: Please define "conversation history".  Is it 1 message?  all messages in a 'thread' (though I don't see any threading)?  all messages for one user?